# Get Data from the JSON Result

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

I am doing in a android project.
Here is my json string looks,

```
{"objectA":{"objectB","objectC","objectD":[{"Element1":"value1","Element2":"value2"}]}}
```

I try to get objectD `JSONArray`.

first I got JSON Result to `jsonStr variable.`

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
```

Then I add that objectD to `JSONArray`

```
JSONArray array1 = jsonObj.getJSONArray("objectD");
```

Then I try to get values of that array

```
for (int i = 0; i < array1.length(); i++) {

JSONObject c = array1.getJSONObject(i);

String myString1 = c.getString("Element1");

String myString2 = c.getString("Element2");

//Then I put those to HashMap

HashMap<String, String> p = new HashMap<String, String>();

p.put(Element1, myString1 );
p.put(Element2, myString2 );

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> q = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

q.add(p);

}
```

When I am debuging my code It shows that `jsonStr` has the json string.

but `p` and `q` don't have values.

How I got those values??

Comment: Move `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> q = new new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();` outside for loop

Comment: I did that. But It didn't work - @ρяσѕρєя K

Comment: When working with json data, I always create POJO objects and then use Jackson or Gson to convert the data to/from json format.  It makes it so much easier and less error prone.  I find Jackson to be more powerful but Gson easier to use for simple cases.

Comment: Can someone help in this approach??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The json you're providing isn't valid json ([jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com)). You have names `objectB`, `objectC` that don't have values. I don't know exactly how this will affect the subsequent suggestions.
I'm kinda surprised the json didn't parse and throw an exception. Maybe it just trashed the bad elements.

From the 'root' of the json you're attempting to get `objectD`; which doesn't exist at the root. You have to first get `objectA`; then get `objectD`.

```
JSONObject objA = jsonObj.getJSONObject("objectA");
JSONArray arrD = objA.getJSONArray("objectD");
```

The recommendation of @GaryBak to use Jackson or GSON is seconded. It's much easier to maintain.

As for debugging; `p` and `q` not having values doesn't tell us much. What does `jsonObj` hold; what does `array1` hold? The more pieces of information you can provide simplifies the process of providing possible solutions.